# How do i print a line from an imported text file in java if the inputted int is found in that text file?

Tags: java, text, import

I'm making a Java "text clock" that prints out the inputted value in English e.g.

```
input: 15:30 
output: fifteen thirty
```

my text file is holding

```
01= one 
02= two 
03= three
...
15= fifteen and so on
```

Is there a way I can link the text file with my java program so that when let's say 01 is inputted by the user. The program will look for 1 in the text file and print out "One". Would this be possible to do

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use your file as a dictionary of sorts to translate user input in your java program?

Comment: Sure it is. Use `Files.readAllLines()`.

Comment: @DennisW Ye that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to follow:

- Try creating a map that reads the file whose key would be String (a number representation) and value would be string representation.
- Read the user input and split it by ":" which will give you an array of length two.
- Look up in a map for number before ":" i.e. array[0] and print it
- Look up in a map for number after ":" i.e. array[1] and print it.

Comment: That's sounds good. Do you have any links to where I can learn more about maps? Thanks

Comment: Begin with [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Try to use these api's and see how it works.